# Same controller for details and edit in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularJs application designed to handle some kind of Items. I have an html template to show detailed information about an Item and another template to edit those details. I would usually use two separate controllers, one for each feature since it's usually best practice to separate the concerns.

But this time I wonder if I should not use a single controller, since the only difference will be that one of the template will call a save method, while the other will not.
Would it be a wrong way to use Angular ? Would it go against it's philosophy ?

Comment: Having 10 very simple controllers or 5 more advanced - this is up to u.

Comment: well, I used to write application with the latter approach ,which is quite OK. It's pro is that we need not to write code more than one times, code-redundancy  is removed.But it gets complex if functionality increases. First approach is cleaner and easy to maintain. That my Opinion.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yes, It's very subjective questions, although it gets tougher with time to maintain 5 advance ones.

Comment: @all seem you said things I expected, I was thinking that there may be something specific to angular, but nobody yet suggested anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to read this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure#a-better-structure-and-foundation).

As you can see, the best practice for file structure in angular is something like this:

```
app/
----- shared/   // acts as reusable components or partials of our site
---------- sidebar/
--------------- sidebarDirective.js
--------------- sidebarView.html
---------- article/
--------------- articleDirective.js
--------------- articleView.html
----- components/   // each component is treated as a mini Angular app
---------- home/
--------------- homeController.js
--------------- homeService.js
--------------- homeView.html
---------- blog/
--------------- blogController.js
--------------- blogService.js
--------------- blogView.html
----- app.module.js
----- app.routes.js assets/
----- img/      // Images and icons for your app
----- css/      // All styles and style related files (SCSS or LESS files)
----- js/       // JavaScript files written for your app that are not for angular
----- libs/     // Third-party libraries such as jQuery, Moment, Underscore, etc. index.html
```

Comparing your thoughts with this, you are right - if it is possible, always make one controller with it's functions for one class/item.

Comment: Thank you but I already read it, along with this one in fact , you might find it interesting https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y081

Comment: It will be helpful for my education. Thanks!

Comment: Don't hesitate to up my comment if it is useful :)